# Asterisk AGI Record File Command

Tags: c#, asterisk

I'm using the Asterisk.Net library for my FastAGI. I do RecordFileCommand and I know it was saved on the var/lib/asterisk/sound directory. My question is how to get the recorded file using the Asterisk.Net library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling you're going to need to look for another method outside of the library in order to retrieve the file.

As a developer in other languages, I would probably have a script to do post processing of my files, for example, you can use the `h` extension to do post processing on a file.

In this example I show, I use the system command to copy a file using the system shell. I copy the file from where monitored conversations are stored to a shared mount point.

That would be my suggestion if you wish to do post processing of audio files off-host.

```
exten => _X.,1,Answer()
same =>      n,AGI(agi://10.0.0.8/yourApp)
same =>      n,MixMonitor(recording.ulaw)
same =>      n,Dial(SIP/example/8005551212)
exten =>   h,1,System(cp /var/spool/asterisk/monitor/recording.ulaw /mnt/shared)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you can't.

The extender answer, as dougBTV points out is to use an alternative method.

If you wish to do it immediately within the .net application, the best bet is to download the file using SSH with [SharpSSH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpssh/)

Excuse the vb.net:

```
Imports Tamir.SharpSsh.java.io
Imports Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch

            'Connect to the SFTP server
            jsch = New JSch()
            session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port)
            session.setPassword(password)
            Dim config2 As Hashtable = New Hashtable()
            config2.Add("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no")
            session.setConfig(config2)
            session.connect()

            sftp = DirectCast(session.openChannel("sftp"), ChannelSftp)
            sftp.connect()

            sftp.get(sftpPath,localpath)
```

You could also stream the file into memory.  From there you can convert / store the file etc.